# GraalVM on MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, graalvm

I have just downloaded and manually install GraalVM on MacOS Catalina as said on https://www.graalvm.org/docs/getting-started/macos/ :

download
unzip

```
 sudo mv graalvm-ce-java11-21.1.0 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    11.0.11, x86_64:    "GraalVM CE 21.1.0" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-21.1.0/Contents/Home
```

configuer in `.zshenv` :

```
export GRAALVM_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-21.1.0/Contents/Home
export JAVA11_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA8_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA11_HOME
export MAVEN_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3
export PATH=$PATH:$GRAALVM_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
```

```
ls $GRAALVM_HOME/bin
gu      javadoc     jdeprscan   jinfo       jps     jstat       pack200     serialver
jar     javap       jdeps       jjs     jrunscript  jstatd      polyglot    unpack200
jarsigner   jcmd        jfr     jlink       js      jvisualvm   rmic
java        jconsole    jhsdb       jmap        jshell      keytool     rmid
javac       jdb     jimage      jmod        jstack      lli     rmiregistry
```

However when I try to run `gu`, `javac` or anything from GRAALVM_HOME, I get MacOS warning

> "graalvm-ce-java11-21.1.0" is damaged and can't be opened

[image]

`sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine $GRAALVM_HOME` as suggested in https://www.graalvm.org/docs/getting-started/macos/ notes does not help.

**How to setup/fix GraalVM on Mac ?**

Comment: Also on https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/3454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with retrying using `tar` and `xattr` *before* moving to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` :

```
Downloads % tar -xzf graalvm-ce-java11-darwin-amd64-21.1.0.tar.gz 
Downloads % sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine ./graalvm-ce-java11-21.1.0/*
```